# Gii model generator error - Table does not exist - Yii framework and SQL Server 2000

Tags: php, yii, sql-server-2000, code-generation, gii

The main configuration of the file ( main.php ) is as follows:

```
'class'=>'CDbConnection',
'connectionString'=>'mssql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=TestSQL'
```

I can connect to the database successfully, but when generating a model from Yii Code Generator it tells me that the table does not exist.

Comment: what is your operating system?

Comment: Windows 7, that overlook settings with later versions sql 2000 works and lets me create the models and all the crud, but immediately make the connection to a sql 2000 engine tells me that the table does not exist

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Table exists?
Gii generates a model based on table. First you need to create a table. If you use console version gii, then to need manage console.php config.

Comment: You can also enable logging of queries, it may help in solving the problem.

Comment: of course the table exists, including all works perfectly but over sql server 2000 verisones!

Comment: in application.log file logs the following error when building the model:

http://pastie.org/8610720

Comment: You are using the latest version of framework ?
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/commit/27899cc320cb1768cc67bdfef572d4270c14f743

"In case you're using MSSQL driver make sure authentication credentials you use have permissions to use
 +  `sys.extended_properties` system view. This is critical for retrieving additional metadata on tables."

Comment: I am using the version v1.1.14, looking at permits the user of this correctly, I have a question since the sql 2000 version uses a different syntax to later versions, an example of this would be:

2000:

SELECT * FROM sysobjects

2008

SELECT *
FROM sys.objects

Comment: sorry I'm very new using yii framework, how this functionality is enabled?

Comment: enable 'CWebLogRoute' class, comparing the result of querys from an application connected to a sql 2000 and one to a sql 2008 there is an object in the query does not exist error for sql 2000 is as follows:

Invalid object name 'sys.extended_properties'.

I can do in this case?
no other. dll serve me for sql 2000?

thanks

Comment: As I understood from this thread discussion, now yii not support MSSQL  below 2005 http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/11395-should-we-support-sql-server-2005-or-above-only/

Comment: yes sir, thank you very much for the help, resolved the doubt, force plays migrated to higher versions

Comment: speaking of logging, I recomend to usethis extension http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-debug-toolbar/

Answer (score -1):

Found Solution renamed the table name to different name and regenerated the model using gii, the things started working again!